# codeigniter Php page not updating with new code

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

i have a signupview page where has include('header.php') at the top and include('footer.php') at the bottom.
These are external php pages.  Just yesterday when i make a change to the footer.php or even delete it from the server the signupview page still have the footer.php there.  But the header.php seems fine if i make changes.

I tried clear cache the browser still nothing.

Comment: Maybe you are not editing the correct file? And maybe you can use `$this->load->view()` instead of the native php function `include()` 
?

Comment: the footer.php file there are constant text and i did entire search on the text to see if there is another footer file somewhere but that's the only one.  Also with caching shouldn't it cache the entire signupview page including header.php?  But changing the header.php file i can see the changes.  very strange

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter has caching mechanism. Just check your cache folders to see if the file is being cached.

Comment: i believe the cache folder should be under application/cache?  If footer.php is in there that most probably be the reason

Comment: As far as I know, there won't be a footer file, rather a cached version of the entire page. CI can cache specific sections as well, but you need to specify that in your code. Any luck?

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem.

And there is no related cache files found in application/cache folder.

But there are 2 ways I found: 1/After refreshing the page several times, the page rendered from edited server code got reflected. OR 2/Waiting for some minutes & refreshing the page, the page is updated as the updated code of server page.